# stopService & stopSelf not working as intended

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a mileage tracking app for a class project and am having issues stopping the mileage tracking service. My "home" activity starts the service with:

```
private void startGPSTracking() {
        startService(new Intent(this, GPSTracking.class));
    }
```

and when the user clicks on the stop trip button, the following is called:

```
    private void stopGPSTracking() {
    //TODO this isn't stopping the service
    stopService(new Intent(this, GPSTracking.class));
    Toast.makeText(Home.this, "Trip Recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("Stop GPS Tracking", "Tracking Stopped");
}
```

I'm getting the toast and log entry but it's like the service is still listening. My app crashes because the requestLocationUpdates() is invoked but there isn't a valid / open trip. The same scenario occurs with the stopSelf() within the tracking service.

```
public class GPSTracking extends Service {
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

//get user ID from authentication
String user_uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

//gets current GPS DB record
DatabaseReference databaseGPS = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("gps").child(user_uid);

//gets current profile DB record
DatabaseReference databaseProfile = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("profiles").child(user_uid);

String key;
double curLat, curLong, startLat, startLong, endLat, endLong = 0;
long curTime, startTime, endTime = 0;
double cost, mileage_rate;
int pause_time, count;
long duration;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    databaseProfile.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mileage_rate = dataSnapshot.child("mileage_rate").getValue(double.class);

            pause_time = dataSnapshot.child("pause_time").getValue(int.class);
            pause_time = pause_time--;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    callPermissions();
}

private void loginToFirebase() {
    String email = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    //TODO how do you authenticate Realtime database with FirebaseAuth user?
    String password = "xxxxxxxx";

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult>task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                addNewTrip();
            } else {
                Log.d("GPS Service", "Firebase Authentication failed");
            }
        }
    });
}


private void addNewTrip() {
    double cost = 54.5;

    Trip trip = new Trip(mileage_rate);

    key = databaseGPS.push().getKey();
    Log.e("addNewTrip", "key: " + key);

    databaseGPS.child(key).setValue(trip).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                //key = databaseGPS.getKey();

                Toast.makeText(GPSTracking.this, "Trip Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                requestLocationUpdates();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(GPSTracking.this, "Problem Starting Trip", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void requestLocationUpdates() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        fusedLocationProviderClient = new FusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(60000);
        locationRequest.setInterval(60000);

        fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

                curLat = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
                curLong = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();
                curTime = locationResult.getLastLocation().getTime();


                if (curLat != 0 && curLong != 0 && startLat == 0 && startLong == 0) {
                    //starting a trip - start & end values are null
                    Log.e("Location", "Just starting trip");

                    updateStartpoint();
                    updateEndpoint();
                    return;
                } else if ((curLat == endLat || curLong == endLong) && count == pause_time) {
                    //pause time reached - close the trip and complete calculations
                    updatedEndTime();

                    duration = endTime - startTime;
                    databaseGPS.child(key).child("duration").setValue(duration);
                    Log.e("Location", "Ending a trip");
                    initializeTrip();
                    stopGPSTracking();
                    return;
                } else if ((curLat == endLat || curLong == endLong) && count < pause_time) {
                    //driving paused but pause time not reached - update pause time & increment count
                    Log.e("Location", "trip paused");
                    updatedEndTime();
                    count++;
                    return;
                } else if ((curLat != startLat || curLong != startLong || curLat != endLat || curLong != endLong) && endTime != 0) {
                    //trip started but driving not paused - update ends
                    Log.e("Location", "driving");
                    if (curLat == endLat) { Log.e("Driving", "curLat == endLat"); };
                    count = 0;
                    updateEndpoint();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }, getMainLooper());
    } else callPermissions();
}

public void callPermissions() {
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
    String rationale = "GPS Tracking - Please provide location permission to allow AutoMile to track your mileage.";
    Permissions.Options options = new Permissions.Options()
            .setRationaleDialogTitle("Info")
            .setSettingsDialogTitle("Warning");

    Permissions.check(this/*context*/, permissions, rationale, options, new PermissionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onGranted() {
            loginToFirebase();
            Log.e("gpstracking", "permission granted");
        }

        @Override
        public void onDenied(Context context, ArrayList<String> deniedPermissions) {
            super.onDenied(context, deniedPermissions);

            callPermissions();
        }
    });
}

public void updateStartpoint() {
    startLat = curLat;
    startLong = curLong ;
    startTime = curTime;

    databaseGPS.child(key).child("start_lat").setValue(startLat);
    databaseGPS.child(key).child("start_long").setValue(startLong);
    databaseGPS.child(key).child("start_time").setValue(startTime);
}

public void updateEndpoint() {
    endLat = curLat;
    endLong = curLong;
    endTime = curTime;

    Log.e("Location", " Update End Point called: " + count);
    databaseGPS.child(key).child("end_lat").setValue(endLat);
    databaseGPS.child(key).child("end_long").setValue(endLong);
    databaseGPS.child(key).child("end_time").setValue(endTime);
}

private void updatedEndTime() {
    endTime = curTime;
    databaseGPS.child(key).child("end_time").setValue(endTime);
}

private void initializeTrip() {
    key = null;
    curLat = 0;
    curLong = 0;
    curTime = 0;
    startLat = 0;
    startLong = 0;
    startTime = 0;
    endLat = 0;
    endLong = 0;
    endTime = 0;
    cost = 0;
    mileage_rate = 0;
    pause_time = 0;
    count = 0;
    duration = 0;
}

private void stopGPSTracking() {
    //TODO this isn't stopping the service
  //stopService(new Intent(this, GPSTracking.class));
    stopSelf();
    Toast.makeText(GPSTracking.this, "Trip Recorded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("Stop GPS Tracking", "Tracking Stopped");
    }
}
```

I'm sure my code is poorly formed and this question has been asked a million times but I can't seem to figure out how to apply it to my scenario. Thank you for you gentleness, kindness and any insight you have.

Answer (score 0):

You should override onDestroy() in your service and unregister the location callback. If you don't do this, it will continue listening after you stop the service.